# The inf-convolution of $2$ convex l.s.c. is convex l.s.c.?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, convex-analysis, convolution, topological-vector-spaces

> Let $E$ be a t.v.s. and $f, g:E \to (-\infty, +\infty]$ be convex l.s.c. such that $f,g \not \equiv +\infty$. We define the infimal-convolution $f \square g:E \to [-\infty, +\infty]$ by
> $$
> (f \square g)(x) := \inf_{y\in E} [f(x-y) + g(y)], \quad \forall x\in E.
> $$

From [Wikipedia](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Convex_conjugate#/Infimal_convolution), $f \square g$ is convex l.s.c. if $E =\mathbb R^n$. Does this property still hold in case $E$ is a t.v.s. or a n.v.s?

---

**Update:**

1. It's written in Robert Phelps's texbook *Convex functions, monotone operators, and differentiability* that

[image]

2. In below attempt, I'm stuck proving the existence of such $y_0$.

It's clear that $(x,y) \mapsto f(x-y)$ and $(x,y) \mapsto g(y)$ are l.s.c., so is the sum $\phi:(x,y) \mapsto f(x-y)+g(y)$. It follows that $\operatorname{epi} \phi := \{(x, y, \lambda) \mid \phi (x,y) \le \lambda\}$ is closed. Our goal is to show that $\operatorname{epi} (f \square g)$ is closed. Fix $\epsilon>0$. Assume $(x_n, \lambda_n)$ is a sequence in $\operatorname{epi} (f \square g)$ such that $x_n \to x\in E$ and $\lambda_n \to \lambda \in \mathbb R$. We want to show that $(x,\lambda) \in \operatorname{epi} (f \square g)$.

For each $n$, there is $y_n \in E$ such that $\phi(x_n, y_n) \le \lambda_n +\epsilon$. If there exist $\color{blue}{y_0}\in E$ and a subsequence $(y_{n_m})_m$ such that $y_{n_m} \to y_0$ as $m \to \infty$, then by l.s.c. of $\phi$ we get $\phi(x,y_0) \le \lambda+\varepsilon$. The claims then follows.

Comment: Convexity should follow from the epigraph characterisation and the fact that the map $X \times X \times \mathbb{R} \ni (x,z,\lambda)\mapsto (x,\lambda)\in X \times \mathbb{R}$ is linear. Here $X$ is your t.v.s

Comment: @almosteverywhere Can you leave some hints about l.s.c.?

Comment: I would try using the characterisation of l.s.c as the epigraph is closed. Then, show that if the epigraph of $f(x-y)+g(y)$ is closed in $X \times X \times \mathbb{R}$, then the same must hold true for the epigraph of $f \square g$ in $X \times \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The exercise by Phelps is wrong: $f(x) = x$, $g(x) = -x$ on $E = \mathbb R$. Here, the inf-convolution is constant $-\infty$.

Comment: @gerw It's in the section `3.9. Exercises.` and at page $42$. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r-RUI92nt-iYrr4JrDINo0tb_dNlgf3A/view?usp=sharing) is the link to the textbook in case you don't have access to it.

Comment: @Analyst: Thank you. I had looked in the first edition, which does not have exercises...

Comment: @gerw In your example, the inf-convolution is not proper. If we know that the inf-convolution is proper, can we show that it is l.s.c.?

Comment: @almosteverywhere I have updated my thread with a failed attempt. Could you please check it out?

Comment: Note that in my example, the inf-convolution is still lsc.

Comment: @gerw suree, I mean to to prove the result, i.e., "$f \nabla g$ is a l.s.c. convex..." instead of "$f \nabla g$ is a proper l.s.c. convex...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is wrong.

Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are indicator functions of sets $A$ and $B$ respectively.
Then $f\Box g$ is the indicator function of the set
$$A+B $$

Now assume that $A$ and $B$ are convex closed nonempty.
Then $f$ and $g$ are convex, lower semicontinuous, and proper.
However, $A+B$ is convex and nonempty, but not necessarily closed:
Indeed, if $X=\mathbb{R}^2$, then let $A$ and $B$ be  the epigraphs of
$\exp(x)$ and $\exp(-x)$ respectively.
Then $A+B$ is the *open upper halfplane* in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
In particular, $A+B$ is not closed.
Hence the infimal convolution is not lower semicontinuous.

*Note:* For some conditions guaranteeing that $f\Box g$ is lower semicontinuous, see Proposition 15.7 in the book by Bauschke-Combettes. For instance, $f$ is coercive and $g$ bounded below would to. Or the domains of $f^*$ and $g^*$ overlap sufficiently.

Answer (score 0):

This might be cheating but you can use one of the convolution theorems if you know it will be proper. See Rockafellar Theorem 16.4. Which allows you to describe the said infimum convolution as a Legendre transform, which would automatically imply it is lsc.

If you don't want to cheat you can Hahn-Banach your way through the epigraph and show that the function is a supremum over continuous affine functionals. (which to me is too tedious).